# Call to undefined function oci_connect() in Heroku app

Tags: java, php, ruby, heroku

I have a problem in my code. I need to push code to Heroku (running on Ubuntu 14.04); my code is PHP and Oracle database. `oci_connect()` works perfectly in localhost and connect successfully to the Oracle database but when I push to Heroku it's returning "`Call to undefined function oci_connect()`". I tried to install bitbucket-heroku like Ruby and Java, but nothing has worked for me yet.

Image: [Heroku error app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAZbC.png)
[image]

This is my link in Heroku: https://serene-anchorage-79470.herokuapp.com/home.php?language=en

My config code:

```
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'pass','(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =myhost )(PORT =port )) (CONNECT_DATA =  (SID =sid )))');
if($conn)
{
    echo "Successfully connected to Oracle.\n";

}
else
{
    $err = OCIError();
    echo "Connection failed." . $err[text];
}
```

Comment: On heroku which OS are you using? Linux?

Comment: im using linux ubuntu ... can you help me please?

Comment: which flavor of linux and version? CentOS/Ubuntu/Debian?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 ..

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are missing the [OCI8 PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) which is needed in order to connect to Oracle database using PHP.

If your Oracle database is not hosted on the same server, you will also need to install [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) on the linux server.